# Magento watermark image with new position

Tags: magento, position, watermark

I need to add Base Image Watermark Position in admin -> configuration -> Design.

While doing this. I can view the option in admin side and set the option choosed.

But in creating image with watermark, that new position not working.

Please help me to find.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Classic question but, did you refresh the Config cache and Images cache?

Comment: Yes. i cleared cache..no response